# Update panel no longer waits for task to finish

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have a site that works in Asp.Net 4.0/webforms.

I thought I could just port it over to 4.7 'as is', but I was wrong.

As you can appreciate from the Asp.Net version, there are no 'task awaits' here - just an update panel and a `Async="true"` tag on the page itself.

Why we needed the Async tag on the page in the first place, is unknown to me.

The page in question is an application form, so when the user has finished entering data, they press 'submit'.

Then a long running job is launched (90 secs), followed by a redirect to another page.

Obviously the redirect can't take place until the result of the long running job comes in, so it is in fact a synchronous operation as far as the user is concerned.

Except it no longer works, and I now get the following message:

**An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending**

I'm guessing that the page is no longer waiting for the job to finish but since this kind of stuff is brand new to me, I don't know what the correct way is to go about fixing it.

To give an example these are two methods that I've tried calling from page load

```
async Task WaitForMe()
{
    // This waits 5 secs - no issues.
    await Task.Delay(5000);
}

async Task ThisIsTheRealOne()
{
    // This contains a number of methods plus a
    // WebClient Http Request - it errors with:
    // "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous +
    // operation was still pending"
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - not the one I was expecting.

The method being called (synchronously) subsequently launched an email asynchronously. This worked in Asp.Net 4.0 but I'm guessing not after the introduction of tasks in 4.5+.